# Github API: List the last N public repositories

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to get the 'n' last public repositories from Github, using their API ([here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories))

I'm trying to understand how `List all public repositories` endpoint works, especially the `since` parameter.

What's this parameter? Will that return me a list of repositories whose id is greater than the `since` value?

How can I use it in order to get the 'n' last public repositories? 
For example, I would like to list the 50 last public repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Github search api with the parameters `is:public created:>2018-04-28:18:00:00Z` to get all public repositories created after a specific date. You can pick the datetime of last hour. If you have less than 50 repositories returned just set 2 hour back for instance

#### Using GraphQL API v4 :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "is:public created:>2018-04-28T18:00:00Z", type: REPOSITORY, last: 50) {
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to make the sort by `createdAt` on your side because there are no sort by created date (only by author-date and commiter date check [this](https://help.github.com/articles/sorting-search-results/))

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?payload=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22is%3Apublic%20created%3A%3E2018-04-28T18%3A00%3A00Z%20sort%3Aauthor-date%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20last%3A%2050)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20startCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

#### For Rest API v3

Use https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=is:public%20created:%3E2018-04-28T18:00:00Z and [traversing pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/) with the `Link` header